# Divide overflow in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, division

I have a simple assembly program, where I want to divide two numbers (two byte sized) and print remainder. Here's my code

```
  .model small
.stack 256

.data 
    ten dw 10

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 12 ; divident
    div ten    ; ax/10

    mov ah, 9  ; for printing dx
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; ending program
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

So when I run this code the result is "Divide overflow" and I have no idea why does overflow happens. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried searching for assembly division problems/questions? Your question is not the first one. It's a duplicate of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIV mem16` divides `DX:AX` by the given operand. So you need to zero-extend `AX` into `DX`, with `MOV DX,0` or `XOR DX,DX`I.e.:

```
mov ax,12
xor dx,dx
div ten
```

(Before signed division with `idiv`, use `cwd` to sign-extend AX.)

Another problem with your code is that you seem to assume that `int 21h / ah=9` can be used to print numeric values. That is not the case. If you want to print the value of `DX` (i.e. the remainder) you'll have to convert it into a string first and print that string. Otherwise you'll just get garbage output, and your program might even crash.

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I debug my code everything is correct, but when it tries to print value, it prints garbage in debug mode and "Divide overflow" in normal mode

Comment: In some environments you might end up with `DX` being 0 when your program starts. In those instances the division would work correctly, but you shouldn't rely on this. Use `CWD` and you'll be safe. As for printing garbage, I mentioned why that happens in the second part of my answer. If you only want to print a single digit you could add `'0'` to `DL` after the division and use `int 21h / ah=2`. Or you could implement your own int-to-string function, see e.g. [my answer to this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204659/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-8086?rq=1).

Comment: Your answer eventually helped me and my main program worked (this was just a test). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write "ten DB 10" or "div BYTE PTR ten".

And I am sure if you write something like

```
mov cl, 10
div cl
```

you'll also get what you want. If it should be word division, you must to clear DX, Michael wrote in post below, how.

BTW I don't know, what assembly dialect it is, but do you really need to write this?

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

Doesn't DS point to data section by defaut?

And 09h doesn't do what you want. Take a look at 02h.

Comment: `mov segreg, reg16` is a perfectly valid x86 instruction.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I thought it doesn't work in DOS. (And does sure work in dosbox etc.) I do always write push reg16 / pop segreg.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of something like `mov es,0a000h`. That's not a valid instruction and could be done with `push / pop` instead. Moving a 16-bit GPR to a segment register has been available since the very first x86 models though.

Comment: The problem is not in `mov ds, ax` I tried it in other programs as well and here too

Answer (score -2):

```
.model small
.stack 256

.data 
    ten dw 10

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 12 ; divident
    div ten    ; ax/10
    add dl,48;
    mov ah, 02h  ; for printing dl not the ascii vlaue
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; ending program
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Is this intentionally demonstrating divide overflow from not zeroing DX first?  word operand-size `div` does `DX:AX / word(10)`.  Actually this looks like a copy/paste of the code from the question, with the same comments including the spelling error of dividend.